How to solve unable to verify username, error fetching excel data? | Access token is empty in ms Graph
Hi I am trying to create a telegram bot that takes input and updates the details to a excel file. I have connected excel file through azure portal and its api using ms graph. I have successfully fetched its access token too earlier i had problems with it but i figured it out and now still it shows error fetching username. Do I need to add username in excel manually to make it update or it will do on its own below is my excel code check it our.
def save_username(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    username = update.message.text
    if username.lower() == 'back':
        return start(update, context)  # Go back to start
    context.user_data['username'] = username

# Check if username exists in Excel
    data = read_excel()
    if data and 'values' in data:
        usernames = [row[1] for row in data['values']]  # Assuming username is in the second column
    if username in usernames:
        update.message.reply_text(
                    'Username already exists. Please try again with a different username.'
                )
    return SAVE_USERNAME
    else:
# Username does not exist, proceed to the next step
    reply_keyboard = [['Back']]
    update.message.reply_text('Please enter your email:',
                              reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
                              reply_keyboard,
                              one_time_keyboard=True))
                return SAVE_EMAIL
        else:
            logger.error(
                "Failed to fetch Excel data. Unable to verify username.")
            update.message.reply_text(
                'Error fetching data. Please try again later.')
            return ConversationHandler.END

As i said earlier I had trouble with the access token so i created new client secret in azure portal and connecting it worked. I tested it in another get access token file the code is below
import msal

from hi.py import TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET


def get_access_token():
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}"
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        CLIENT_ID,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET
    )
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

    if "access_token" in result:
        print("Access token acquired successfully")
        return result['access_token']
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve access token: {result.get('error')}")
        if "error_description" in result:
            print(f"Error description: {result['error_description']}")
        if "correlation_id" in result:
            print(f"Correlation ID: {result['correlation_id']}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_access_token()

I am unabe to save username in the excel file do i need to add username in the first row. The excel file is completely empty.
Updates
Now it shows
_main_ - ERROR - Error fetching data: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/61814971F1322FC0!1070/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1:F1000')
and the site shows
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2024-07-16T09:32:26","request-id":"36c2f98e-6ebd-445a-9b2f-7a103b1be037","client-request-id":"36c2f98e-6ebd-445a-9b2f-7a103b1be037"}}}

so i tested getting access token by the following code
import msal

from hi import TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET


def get_access_token():
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}"
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        CLIENT_ID,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET
    )
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

    if "access_token" in result:
        print("Access token acquired successfully")
        return result['access_token']
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve access token: {result.get('error')}")
        if "error_description" in result:
            print(f"Error description: {result['error_description']}")
        if "correlation_id" in result:
            print(f"Correlation ID: {result['correlation_id']}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_access_token()

and ti prints
python ./access_token.py
2024-07-16 09:30:23,127 - msal.authority - INFO - Initializing with Entra authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/ed586964-ec89-4ecb-95bf-df20fb9axxxx
Access token acquired successfully
The error now is access toke is empty in ms graph link.

The error 400 occurred as you are generating token via ConfidentialClientApplication and calling /me endpoint.

ConfidentialClientApplication generates token without user interaction whereas  /me  supports token which is generated by user interactive flow.
ConfidentialClientApplication requires application permissions and supports users/UserID endpoint only.
Hence, you cannot call /me endpoint while generating token via ConfidentialClientApplication.

As your requirement is to update the worksheet, you need to make use of delegated permissions and make use of user interactive flow as updating worksheet is not supported for application permissions (That is token generated by ConfidentialClientApplication too is not supported too). Refer this MsDoc.
Hence you need to generate access token using any user interactive flow and grant delegated permissions only:

And make use of below code to generate access token:
import logging
import msal

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("main")

CLIENT_ID = "ClientID"
TENANT_ID = "TenantID"
SCOPES = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

def get_access_token():
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}"
    app = msal.PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=authority)

    try:
        result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=SCOPES)
        access_token = result.get('access_token')
        if access_token:
            return access_token
        else:
            error_msg = result.get('error_description', result.get('error', 'Unknown error'))
            logger.error(f"Failed to retrieve access token: {error_msg}")
            raise Exception(f"Could not retrieve access token: {error_msg}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Exception while retrieving access token: {str(e)}")
        raise

# Example usage:
try:
    token = get_access_token()
    print("Access token:", token)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", str(e))

This will redirect to the browser to sign in:

And access token is generated:

And now use the above generated access token to update the worksheet that is call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/ItemID/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1:F1000') API and now you will not get 400 error.

The error is due passing invalid access token not with the API call.
You can make use of any delegated flow to resolve the error. Make sure not to use ConfidentialClientApplication flow.
Make sure to grant Files.ReadWrite delegated type API permission only to the application.

Reference:
MSAL Python 1.30.0 documentation (msal-python.readthedocs.io)

Hi there thanks for the guide I did everyhting as you said but the redirected link says no reply address is registered for the application.

I am using replit by the way do i need to add some sort of URLs.  And if so where and how.

Redirect URI must be http://localhost in Mobile & desktop applications platform along with enabling public client flow option in the application

i am trying too connect a telegram bot and I am thinking of deploying that code to replit to make the bot run 24/7. So will the replit.com as a url would be enough?

I am not so sure about the telegram bot but in my environment to make it work I added http://localhost as redirect url

@AmanPrakashSingh any update on the issue?
